# 'Prefer' and 'Recommend' in Japanese

Tags: translation, meaning

what is prefer in Japanese ? 
an example of the context is:

> I'd rather not to drink inside the bus.

おすすめ is recommend in Japanese. how would you use おすすめ in this context?

> it is recommended not to buy that bag.

Comment: Although I'm not a native English speaker, I think your sentence is ill-formed. I can understand `I'd rather not drink inside the bus` and `I prefer not to drink inside the bus`, but you mixed both in a sentence that sounds like you **prefer to prefer** or **want to prefer**, which is probably a mistake, right?

Comment: If you want to say "thank you in advance", it's よろしくお願いします.

Comment: @Hamsteriffic thank you for correcting my mistake ! I had noticed that I had formed an incorrect sentence as well !

Comment: @brokenheadphones thank you for telling me !

Comment: A question is considered resolved when the asker accepts an answer, there is no need to edit the title to reflect that it is solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what is prefer in Japanese ? an example of the context is:
>
> "I'd rather prefer not to drink inside the bus."

You could use:

「Verb + nominalizer の + は + 好{す}きではない / 望{のぞ}まない」 to form:

> 「バスの中{なか}でものを飲{の}むのは好きではない。」

Or a little more naturally,

> 「バスの中でものを飲んだりするのは（あまり）好きではない。」

Next..

> おすすめ is recommend in Japanese. how would you use おすすめ in this context?
>
> "it is recommended not to buy that bag."

You could say:

> 「あのバッグを買{か}うのは**おすすめ**できません。」
>
> 「あのバッグを買うのは**おすすめ**ではありません。」

Without using the verb 「買う」, you could also say:

> 「あのバッグは**おすすめ**ではありません。」
>
> 「あれは**おすすめ**のバッグではありません。」

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does the 飲んだりする construction instead of plain 飲む sound more natural?